# SQL command with GROUP_CONCAT and empty values

Tags: mysql, sql

I've got 1 SQL command to select data from 2 different tables.

First table is "sections" (id, title, text) and second table is "sections_multimedia" (id, section_id, filename)

I use GROUP_CONCAT to get all the sections of the page and each one's multimedia (photos)

My command is the following:

```
SELECT s.*, GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT_WS(':', sm.id, sm.filename) SEPARATOR ',') AS multimedia
                                FROM sections AS s, sections_multimedia AS sm
                                WHERE s.id = sm.section_id
                                GROUP BY sm.section_id
                                ORDER BY s.id ASC;
```

Table "sections" and table "sections_multimedia" are connected via "section_id" field of "sections_multimedia" table.

The above SQL command works perfectly, the only problem is:
When a row from "sections" table has nothing in table "sections_multimedia" it is not showed in the results.

What can i do to grab all data from table "sections" no matter if they have or not any data in "sections_multimedia" table?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.  In your case, you want a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT s.*,
       GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT_WS(':', sm.id, sm.filename) SEPARATOR ',') AS multimedia
FROM sections s LEFT JOIN
     sections_multimedia sm
     ON s.id = sm.section_id
GROUP BY s.id
ORDER BY s.id ASC;
```

Comment: Thank you Gordon! Worked like a charm!I hope this command will be fast with 4.000 entries in "sections" with about 10 photos in each one!